# com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to progamatically compile and load protobuf code in an eclipse plugin but for some reason it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

I know I have the dependencies set up correctly because I am able to import ExtensionRegistroyLite and use it. Also when I run this code as a Java application it works fine. Here is how I am compiling and loading the class:

```
compiler.run(null, null, null, "-d", "path/to/dir, "-classpath", "protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar", "myProtoClass.java")

URL url = protoDir.toUri().toURL();         
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

// load compiled class
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

// create object of compiled class
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(fullMessageName, true, cl); // Crashes at this line
```

If I scroll down further in the errors it says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Any hints as to what may be causing this would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can see, your classloader only knows about the *directory* containing the protobuf jar file, not the jar file itself. I suspect if you create a URL for the jar file, it will work.

Comment: I tried doing that but still the same error unfortunetly

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you've done that then - if you could provide a [mcve], that would be ideal.